# Ubuntu 11.10 / 12.04 installation freeze - HM67 chipset + SSD Intel 335

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, ssd

I upgraded HDD to Intel SSD 335 in my laptop (Dell Vostro 3750, chipset HM67, latest version of BIOS A14) and i cannot install Ubuntu - i tried three different versions : 32bit 11.10. and 12.04. and 64bit 12.04.

Ubuntu CD boots, then there is welcome screen where i select english language and i confirm installation and then i see only underscore on blank screen - nothing happens after 10min.

Is there any option to choose special HDD driver (i remember that windows installation does have option to press F6 in pre-installation and you can then install custom HDD drivers).

I tried to install Windows 7 and installator asked for SSD driver, is there any hope for Ubuntu installation ?

Comment: try 13.04 ..its very sexy....all drivers included

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but when i formatted SSD on NTFS partition it worked well and Ubuntu installator do not freeze. Previously SSD was empty and then with ext4 partition but for some reason Ubuntu installator did not liked that...